# Why is it considered bad to go more than 2 if statement deep?

Tags: python-2.7

So I've been reading the book Learn Python the Hard Way by Zed Shaw and it says that using more than 2 if statements deep is bad. I'm currently writing a game and it would make more sense to me to use multiple if statements:

```
shoot = -50
zombie_hp = -100

def zombie1(shoot, zombie_hp):
    return shoot - zombie_hp

def attack():   
    attack = raw_input("What will you do?: ")
    print zombie1(zombie_hp, shoot)
    if attack == "shoot":
        if shoot == -50:
            print "Zombie health 50/100"
            attack2 = raw_input("What will you do?: ")
            print zombie1(zombie_hp, shoot)
            if attack == "shoot":
                print "Zombie health 0/100 (Zombie dies)"
attack()
```

Now why is it bad to go 3 if statements deep on this? Thanks!

Comment: Do if attack == shoot and shoot == -50: It's not literally bad (like everything will work) but it depends on the context really. If you can avoid using tons of if statements it makes your code cleaer.

Comment: I think for all languages: it's just ugly to look at. Btw, you don't need the second `if attack == "shoot"` as you already checked for it in your first if statement.

Comment: The problem here isn't depth of nesting per se, it's poor code structure more generally. The inner `if` is a repeat of parts of the outer one, which has left you vulnerable to the mistake of using `attack` instead of `attack2`. Also, the global variables are a bad idea; consider OOP, have a `Zombie` class instance with `health` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take on it is that deeply nested `if` branching can limit how easily your code could be extended.  Given your example, what if in the future you wanted to implement attacks that do different amounts of damage, or zombies with different amounts of hitpoints?  My recommendation would be to avoid consigning yourself to creating explicitly different `if` branching conditions for each different combination of attack sequences and zombies.

This link also gives some more concrete examples of why you might want to avoid this pattern:
http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrowAntiPattern

Answer (score 0):

1) Makes it more difficult for other developers to understand, and more importantly - it makes it harder for yourself to understand when you look back on it later.

2) It makes your code inflexible and brittle.

3) [Tell, don't ask](https://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask)